# How to append lists from a different module in PYTHON 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I am trying to make a text based adventure game in python, as i am a beginner my programming isn't that great so what i have done is great.

I was wondering if you are able to append a list from a different module.
For example at the shop i would import the inventory module and be able to append the inventory list from the shop module.

H.Moss

Comment: Can you please post some code so that we can know what you’re trying to do? An mvce would be great.

Comment: You'd do it the same way as if it were from the same module. Perhaps the problem is really about obtaining the value from the other module.

Comment: i have also used this from inventory import invent

Comment: print("You now have {} coins.".format(gold))
            inv.append("Apple")
            print(inv)

Comment: Why don't you try and find out, instead of asking?

Answer (score 1):

Either you import the list variable from the other module (`from othermodule import list_var`), or import the module and write the variable as `othermodule.list_var`. Either way, you can use it like any other list.

Comment: Thank this has helped out so much :)